# Remove the green warning in excel from react js

Tags: reactjs

[image]

When I download the Excel, I get the green warning in cell I need to remove it.
Here is the code...

```
ApiGet("API")
  .then(async (res) => {
    //i get the URL
    const fileUrl = res.data.data;
    console.log('fileUrl', fileUrl);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(fileUrl);

      const blob = await response.blob();
      // FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `${nameHeader} ${val?.data?.['Short Name']}`);

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = `${val?.data?.['Short Name']} ${nameHeader}`;

      link.click();

      setLoader(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
      setLoader(false);
    }
});
```

I did try but no helpful answer. Can any one help me with this functionality.

Comment: Is this an Excel file you've created?

Comment: Yes, this it created.

Comment: Well you should post *how* you've created/exported this Excel file and not how you are serving it

Comment: What is the warning that Excel is showing you? You aren't doing anything to the content of the file in the code you've shown us so it's unlikely anything to do with that. It could be an issue with the creation of the file on the server.

Comment: Also, why aren't you just firing a `window.open('fileurl') and let the browser handle the download automatically?

Comment: @phuzi - From my experience it's a warning that formulas don't match the previous one - But as pointed out, the current posted code has nothing to do with the issue at thand

Comment: @DarkBee All the more reason to question where the Excel file comes from. bobby Is it dynamically generated somewhere? You should probably be looking there.

Comment: I've already pointed this out in the comments to OP...

Comment: @phuzi  Excel file URL comes from the backend (.net)

Comment: That's what I thought and we'd really need to see the code that creates the Excel file as the issue is most likely during creation of the spreadsheet.

Comment: From my experience, and looking at your screenshot, my best guess is that that error is indicating that those are numbers stored as text. I am guessing this because they are left-justified instead of right (the latter being the preference for numbers in Excel), and this is a common issue in Excel files. As others have suggested, you should check where/how that file is generated. Make sure that those values are getting stored as numbers and "numbers" -- e.g. 62.1 and not "62.1"

Answer (score -2):

I found this, hope it helps.

To stop the green triangle error from showing, you can switch off background error checking in Excel. In the Ribbon, go to File > Options > Formulas > Error Checking. Remove the tick from the Enable background error checking option, and then click OK.

[https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/get-rid-of-green-triangle-excel/#:~:text=To%20stop%20the%20green%20triangle%20error%20from%20showing%2C,background%20error%20checking%20option%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.](https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/get-rid-of-green-triangle-excel/#:%7E:text=To%20stop%20the%20green%20triangle%20error%20from%20showing%2C,background%20error%20checking%20option%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.)

Comment: I need to fix the issue in coding.

Comment: This is not a practical solution and more of a personal preference kind of thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).